# XCode: Horizontal Scrolling in a TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to implement horizontal scrolling on each cell of a TableView.
The principle seems simple:

- Create a cell 5 times bigger than a normal one.
- Add 5 subviews of normal size in the cell (or 5 CustomCell).
- Create a UIScrollView of the same size as the cell.

But I can't get it to work and I've run out of ideas.
What I've tried does nothing; I must be doing something wrong.

I have watched many tutorials and either it is double TableView (which I don't want) or a little part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you are needing to do but this tutorial on making a "Pulse" type UI may spark some ideas [how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)